# What could be causing this simple validation to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My site has Properties and Customers. Customer has_many properties and Property belongs_to Customer.

I also have this validation on Property:

```
validates :name, :uniqueness => { scope: :customer_id }
```

Now usually everything is ok but yesterday we did a big deploy with lots of changes and migrations and now that validation is failing (when doing `customer.save`), even after rolling back to the previous code. the failure is:

```
Validation failed: Properties is invalid
```

When I test locally using the production database, I get the same error. When I use a fresh database locally, it passes.

Something tells me that the database might be corrupted slightly on a Property? Otherwise why would this validation be failing all of a sudden.

How do I debug/fix this?

it actually seems to just be the property with name = "type" that is causing the validation to fail and only when creating a new Customer, not when updating an existing one

Comment: It could be a clash with the 'type' property and Single Table Inheritance. ActiveRecord searches for a column named `type` to implement polymorphism in models that are saved to one table. Seems like a long shot but it may be related somehow. (http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/)

Comment: Are you creating the property and customer at the same time? It may be that the customer has a nil id when the property is created. If, in your production db, you have a `Property.where(name: 'type', customer_id: nil)` then that would cause the error.

Comment: So, you mean that validation fails if you try to create a customer with multiple properties with the same name?